# Logging from an azure console app as a web job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, serilog

I am in search for a good way to log various messages while being able to use functions, logic, monitoring, etc to get notified or run a certain task to fix a problem and notify someone.

What I have in mind is something like "If a specific error happens send me a notification or restart a service"

What I currently already have is an app service that holds 10 web jobs(continuous, triggered). Two of them use the Azure Web job SDK and the rest of them are plain .net core console apps. All of them generate structured logs using serilog and are saved to blob storage.

Is there something I am missing? I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: What about [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use application insights with webjobs, more details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#add-application-insights-logging).

You can also set an alert in application insights if error occurs, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-alert#create-an-alert-from-metrics).

Any more questions please let me know.